# How to vectorize the formation of many rank-1 outer products?

Tags: performance, matlab, vectorization

Can the loop below be vectorized? Each iteration in the loop forms an outer product, then symmetrizes and stores the result as a column in a matrix. It's anticipated that `m` is large (e.g., 1e4) and `s` is small (e.g., 10).

```
% U and V are m-by-s matrices
A = zeros(s^2, m); % preallocate
for k = 1:m
    Ak = U(k,:)' * V(k,:);
    Ak = (Ak + Ak')/2;
    A(:, k) = Ak(:);
end
```

**Edit**

Here is a comparison of 3 different methods: iterate over the the large dimension `m`, iterate over the small dimension `s`, and a `bsxfun` based solution (the accepted and fastest answer).

```
s = 5; m = 100000;
U = rand(m, s);
V = rand(m, s);

% Iterate over large dimension
tic
B = zeros(s^2, m);
for k = 1:m
    Ak = U(k,:)' * V(k,:);
    Ak = (Ak + Ak')/2;
    B(:, k) = Ak(:);
end
toc

% Iterate over small dimension
tic
A = zeros(s, s, m);
for i = 1:s
    A(i,i,:) = U(:, i) .* V(:, i);
    for j = i+1:s
        A(i,j,:) = (U(:,i).*V(:,j) + U(:, j).*V(:, i))/2;
        A(j,i,:) = A(i,j,:);
    end
end
A = reshape(A, [s^2, m]);
toc

% bsxfun-based solution
tic
A = bsxfun( @times, permute( U, [1 3 2] ), permute( V, [ 1 2 3 ] ) );
A = .5 * ( A + permute( A, [1 3 2] ) );
B = reshape( A, [m, s^2] )';
toc
```

Here is a time comparison:

```
Elapsed time is 0.547053 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.042639 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.039296 seconds.
```

Comment: Is the question still relevant after your first optimization? Looks like you got a x10 speedup.

Comment: @EitanT `bsxfun` can get you an extra 50% - see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `bsxfun` (it's how its done with lots of fun):

```
% the outer product
A = bsxfun( @times, permute( U, [1 3 2] ), permute( V, [ 1 2 3 ] ) );
% symmetrization
A = .5 * ( A + permute( A, [1 3 2] ) );
% to vector (per product)
B = reshape( A, [m s^2] )';
```

Benchmark results (my machine):

1. **Original approach** (iterate over large dim):

   ```
    Elapsed time is 0.217695 seconds.
   ```
2. **"New" approach** (iterate over smaller dim):

   ```
    Elapsed time is 0.037538 seconds.
   ```
3. **Fun with `bsxfun`**:

   ```
    Elapsed time is 0.021507 seconds.
   ```

As you can see `bsxfun` takes ~ 2/3 - 1/2 of the time of the fastest loop...

Isn't it just fun with [bsxfun](/questions/tagged/bsxfun)?

Comment: I can see that `bsxfun` does the right thing -- great! But the symmetrization step isn't correct: in particular, `A` and `permute(A,[2 1 3])` aren't compatible sizes.

Comment: I got it to work, but had to change the symmetrization step to `A = .5 * ( A + permute( A, [1 3 2] ) );` and the "to vector" step to `B = reshape( A, [m, s^2] )';`

Comment: @Michael - thanks for the catch. i corrected my solution accrodingly.

Comment: The `reshape` is still missing the transpose operation.

Comment: @Michael at my age, spotting this little `'` is getting dificult... hope I got it right this time.